# sql query entries that exist in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: `requests` (`email`) , `results` (`email`, `data`, `processed_at`)

I want to get an entry from `results` that has `processed_at = null` and an email which exists in `requests`. My current approach is to use a **join**:

```
select `results`.* from `results` 
inner join `requests` on `requests`.`email` = `results`.`email` 
where `results`.`processed_at` is null limit 1
```

Unfortunately this is very slow. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: If you want to get all results, why are you using `limit 1`?

Comment: Add indexes and foreign keys.

Comment: Do you have Index on `email` in `requests` and `results` table. Do you really need to do SELECT * ? Can you reduce it to specific columns you need! SELECT * is inefficient

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @GordonLinoff I actually just want one entry from results that satisfies the conditions. I will update the question.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya yes. the index is set on both tables.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a subquery like:

```
SELECT results.*
FROM results
WHERE results.processed_at IS NULL
    AND results.mail IN (SELECT DISTINCT requests.mail FROM requests)
LIMIT 1
```

However, I'm not sure if it's faster.

Answer (score 0):

select `results`.* from `results` 
left join `requests` on `requests`.`email` = `results`.`email` 
where `results`.`processed_at` is null limit 1

i am quite sure that this is much faster than inner join.